# VS 2022 SSIS Properties to Export not functioning

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2022

The checkboxes are missing! I can't select the properties to export. |It's the first time I'm trying this feature in VS 2022. I have read that this was a issue back in Dec 2022 but was hoping that it has been fixed.

[image]

[image: Duplicate menu items]

VS version 17.6.2

Comment: What happens when you click the Properties check box? Do the missing boxes appear?  Tools, Options, General, Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance". Any better?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions however no luck. I will uninstall and go back a version. I can't delay starting my project and definitely there is something wrong with this version. I right clicked on a package and the displayed menu had duplicate items! I edited my original post ad added an image.

Answer (score 0):

VS 17.16.1 on Windows 10 reporting in

My Package Configuration Wizard shows

[image]

About VS shows

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
Version 17.6.1
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.6.1+33717.318
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Enterprise

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2022   00482-20600-00966-AA485
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2022

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.6.326.62524
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.6.326.62524
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.6.326.62524
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Code Converter   1.0
Code Converter Extension Details

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.23087.1
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.4.21 (main@8f226a8)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.6.41 (790a401)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   6.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Python - Profiling support   17.0.23087.1
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.23087.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.6.0.2326105+37f2727000f6a964584cafb86e69cf0b39baecb7
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

Redgate SQL Prompt   1.0.0.0
Write, format, and refactor SQL effortlessly

SQL Server Data Tools   17.6.13.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   16.0.5131.0
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 16.0.5131.0

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20329.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.6.0-beta.23174.5+0207bea1afae48d9351ac26fb51afc8260de0a97
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Xamarin   17.6.0.251 (d17-6@318364c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.6.6.0 (remotes/origin/d17-6@cb430751d1)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.6.32 (98c12a2)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.0.6 (d17-5/a200af1)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: 6dd9def
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-5@149d70fe
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.1@68c69d8
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-5@9f02d77


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.4.0.6 (97731c92c)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Patching now so we'll see if I break my install... Which it did not

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
Version 17.6.2
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.6.2+33723.286
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Enterprise

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2022   00482-20600-00966-AA485
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2022

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.6.326.62524
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.6.326.62524
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.6.326.62524
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Code Converter   1.0
Code Converter Extension Details

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.23087.1
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.4.21 (main@8f226a8)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.6.41 (790a401)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   6.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Python - Profiling support   17.0.23087.1
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.23087.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.6.0.2326105+37f2727000f6a964584cafb86e69cf0b39baecb7
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

Redgate SQL Prompt   1.0.0.0
Write, format, and refactor SQL effortlessly

SQL Server Data Tools   17.6.13.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   16.0.5131.0
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 16.0.5131.0

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20329.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.6.0-beta.23174.5+0207bea1afae48d9351ac26fb51afc8260de0a97
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Xamarin   17.6.0.251 (d17-6@318364c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.6.6.0 (remotes/origin/d17-6@cb430751d1)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.6.32 (98c12a2)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.0.6 (d17-5/a200af1)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: 6dd9def
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-5@149d70fe
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.1@68c69d8
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-5@9f02d77


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.4.0.6 (97731c92c)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

SSDT/SSIS components didn't change their build number as part of this patch so I'd wager it's something specific to your machine but what that is, is beyond me.